# How to put the time derivatives (dots) on top of the variable x in Gnuplot 5.2 Patchlevel 6a?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to graph the solutions for system of differential equations but my solutions include the time derivatives of the initial conditions and I dont know how to put the dots on top of my variable x.Does anyone knows how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Three possible solutions.

**Solution 1 using UTF8 character encoding**

```
# Unicode U+0307 "COMBINING DOT ABOVE" (derivative Newtonian notation)
# UTF8 hexadecimal byte sequence  0xCC 0x87
# UTF8 escaped octal byte sequence \314\207
set encoding utf8
set title sprintf("initial x\314\207 = 1.23") font "Times:Italic,15"
```

**Solution 2 using gnuplot's own markup sequence**

```
# enhanced text mode overprint "x" with "." raised by 0.8 character height units
# see "help enhanced" for full syntax description
set title "initial {~x{0.8.}} = 4.56" font "Times:Italic,15"
```

**Solution 3 using unicode feature in gnuplot development version (5.3)**

```
set title "initial x\U+0307 = 7.89"
```

All 3 options produce output like this
[image]